# How to tell verilator linter to not verify submodule?

Tags: verilog, verilator

I'm using verilator for linting my design with this commands :

```
verilator -lint-only -Wall top_design.v
```

But some submodule are not available (mainly because it template from FPGA constructor). Then I have these kind of errors :

```
%Error: efb.v:39: Cannot find file containing module: VHI
%Error: efb.v:41: Cannot find file containing module: BB
%Error: efb.v:43: Cannot find file containing module: BB
%Error: efb.v:45: Cannot find file containing module: VLO
%Error: efb.v:97: Cannot find file containing module: EFB
%Error: submod.v:163: Cannot find file containing module: OSCH
```

All submodules mentionned in these errors messages are templates for lattice machxo3 fpga.

Is there a solution to ask verilator to not care about these modules ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to official [verilator forum](https://github.com/verilator/verilator/issues/1933), the only way to do it is to make «null module».